# most popular high availability solutions for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, high-availability

i've heard of lvs:
http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/

and linux ha

and piranha, ultramonkey, keepalived , heartbeat and pacemaker.

Can someone help me make sense of this torrent of solutions?

im looking for a tool that migrates vips between boxes on service fail (http, mysql)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the NSDI paper on [the Remus homepage](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/Remus). There are also information at the homepage of [XEN](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/Remus) about Remus. It is a quite smart solution, and open source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about migrating VIPs you want heartbeat or keepalived.  LVS, piranha, ultramonkey, and pacemaker are all more or less the same thing and give you load-balancing.

Combine both of these together to get failover and load-balancing.

Answer (score 0):

"It depends".  High availability is a broad term and it can be achieved many different ways.  What you need (and is a popular use for) will depend on your specific needs.  LVS is popular for load balancing. Pacemaker on top of corosync or heartbeat is popular for when you need services to fail over between different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

My company sells high-availability Linux solutions for telecom carriers, and we use Linux HA.  From what I understand, there is a daemon that tries to contact the mate via ethernet and/or serial, and when the stand-by node detects that the active node is not responding, it assumes ownership of the VIP (virtual IP, a shared IP address that neither one "owns" full-time, but that either can assume by sending out ARP messages to the router).

This is a high-availability solution only, not a load balancing solution.